# how can I merge all site by packages openair ,importAURN

Tags: r

In package "openair",i want to use 'importAURN' find all 2021 AURN site data in one dataset.
i.e. merge all site data,or have other method find all 2021 AURN site data?
How can i do it.

This code can know all aurn site

```
importMeta(source = "aurn", all = FALSE)
```

each site code like

1.site=kc1

```
kc1 <- importAURN(site = "kc1", year = 2021)
```

date                pm2.5  site                code

1 2021-01-01 00:00:00  30.4 London N. Kensington KC1
2 2021-01-01 01:00:00  55.8 London N. Kensington KC1
3 2021-01-01 02:00:00  28.3 London N. Kensington KC1
4 2021-01-01 03:00:00  15.6 London N. Kensington KC1
5 2021-01-01 04:00:00  19.8 London N. Kensington KC1

2. site=AH

```
AH <- importAURN(site = "AH", year = 2021)
```

date                pm2.5 site     code
1 2021-01-01 00:00:00  5.33 Aberdeen ABD
2 2021-01-01 01:00:00  3.07 Aberdeen ABD
3 2021-01-01 02:00:00  2.64 Aberdeen ABD
4 2021-01-01 03:00:00  2.43 Aberdeen ABD
5 2021-01-01 04:00:00  2.38 Aberdeen ABD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this serves your purpose:

```
dat<- importMeta(source = "aurn", all = FALSE)
imported<- lapply(dat$code, importAURN, year = 2021)
```

This code store all data of `aurn` sites, and then apply `importAURN` function to each site by the code for year `2021`, and then store the resulted data to a list named `imported`. Each element of the list contains the data of each site.

In case you want to merge all data from all elements in the `imported` list, you can use `rbind` this way:

```
merged <- do.call(rbind, imported)
```

For example, I want to import and then merge dataset from the first two sites:

```
first2sites <-lapply(dat$code[1:2], importAURN, year = 2021)
merged2 <- do.call(rbind, first2sites)
head(merged2)
# # A tibble: 6 x 12
# site     code  date                  nox   no2    no    o3  pm10 pm2.5    ws    wd air_temp
# <chr>    <fct> <dttm>              <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl>
#   1 Aberdeen ABD   2021-01-01 00:00:00  4.51 3.41  0.718  58.5  8.7   5.33   6    338.      3.9
# 2 Aberdeen ABD   2021-01-01 01:00:00  3.76 2.79  0.628  57.3  6     3.07   6.1  339.      3.9
# 3 Aberdeen ABD   2021-01-01 02:00:00  3.69 2.66  0.673  54.9  5.08  2.64   5.9  341.      4.4
# 4 Aberdeen ABD   2021-01-01 03:00:00  1.54 0.815 0.471  55.2  4.78  2.43   6.9  345.      4.1
# 5 Aberdeen ABD   2021-01-01 04:00:00  3.07 2.15  0.605  52.2  5.03  2.38   7    347.      3.7
# 6 Aberdeen ABD   2021-01-01 05:00:00  3.94 3.02  0.605  49.9  6.32  2.81   6.9  352.      3.5

tail(merged2)
# # A tibble: 6 x 12
# site                 code  date                  nox   no2    no    o3  pm10 pm2.5    ws    wd air_temp
# <chr>                <fct> <dttm>              <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl>
#   1 Aberdeen Erroll Park ABD9  2021-12-31 18:00:00  175.  57.8  76.2  2.39  21.1  16.2   3.4  127.      5.4
# 2 Aberdeen Erroll Park ABD9  2021-12-31 19:00:00  143.  53.7  58.4  2.00  30.4  25.4   3.6  156.      5.9
# 3 Aberdeen Erroll Park ABD9  2021-12-31 20:00:00  175.  53.9  79.1  2.39  45.2  27.2   3.8  167.      6.4
# 4 Aberdeen Erroll Park ABD9  2021-12-31 21:00:00  177.  53.0  81.1  2.79  61.5  42.4   3.9  189.      6.9
# 5 Aberdeen Erroll Park ABD9  2021-12-31 22:00:00  215.  56.2 104.   2.79  41.0  29.6   4.4  194.      7.4
# 6 Aberdeen Erroll Park ABD9  2021-12-31 23:00:00  160.  43.7  75.9  8.98  25.3  20.6   5.9  200.      7.6
```